# 23LC1024 manual programming

Tags: arduino

I recently bought a [23LC1024](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/23A1024-23LC1024-1-Mbit-SPI-Serial-SRAM-with-SDI-and-SQI-Interface-DS20005142.pdf) which is a SRAM chip. I followed a tutorial in which the testing program had only `#include <SPI.h>` in it, and it worked without problems.

I actually tested both with a real Arduino Uno and in the Proteus simulator with an Arduino Uno component, and both worked.

I also read the datasheet and figured out from there a way of communicating with it. This part is exactly what I want to test.

Here are two diagrams from the datasheet that I used all the time while coding:

[image]

[image]

With help from the Arduino forums, I advanced to a point where I get a result, but is not the correct result.

What I am doing in this code: I am directly accessing the pins of the RAM, by a method called 'Bit Banging'. I am hardcoding the instructions, and sending them manually as simply as possible.

The result is still incorrect. Please, advise me where the problem is that I can't see?

This is the output console from the Proteus simulator. The transmitted bits should be the same in the received/read bits.
I am clearly missing something, but what?

[image]

**The folowing is the Arduino code:**

```
#include "Arduino.h"

/************SRAM opcodes: commands to the 23LC1024 memory chip ******************/

#define clk        13 // Manual Serial Clock
#define wpin       12 // Write pin
#define rpin       11 // Read pin
#define cspin      10 // Chip Select

/************Global Variables*********************/

byte bcode = 0b11100111; // test bitcode to send/receive only once

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(clk, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(wpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(cspin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(cspin,LOW); // ChipSelect CS is Low to start and High to end a read/write operation.
  digitalWrite(rpin,LOW); // initialize read pin as Output Low

  /*
  --------------------------
  ---------Writing----------
  --------------------------
  */
  digitalWrite(cspin, LOW); // starting write operation
  Serial.println("Transmiting data:");
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);

  //-------------1st: 8bit initialization-------------
  //this is 00000010
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clk, 1);
    digitalWrite(wpin, 0); // only 6 0's
    digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  }
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 1); // 7th bit
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 0); // 8th bit
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  
  //-------------2nd: 24bit address-------------------
  //this is 00000000 00000000 00000001
  for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clk, 1);
    digitalWrite(wpin, 0); // last 23 addr bits
    digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  }
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 1); // first 1 addr bit (reading from R to L)
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);

  //-------------3rd 8bit code-----------------------
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, bcode); // WRITE bitcode into RAM address
  Serial.println(bcode, BIN);
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);

 //CSpin
 digitalWrite(clk, 1);
 // from datasheet: "A write is terminated by the CS being brought high"
 digitalWrite(cspin,HIGH); // finishing write operation
 digitalWrite(clk, 0);
 digitalWrite(clk, 1);
 digitalWrite(cspin,LOW); // starting read operation
 digitalWrite(clk, 0);

  /*
  --------------------------
  ---------Reading----------
  --------------------------
  */
  Serial.println("Receiving data:");

  //-------------1st: 8bit initialization-------------
  // this is 00000011
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clk, 1);
    digitalWrite(wpin, 0); // only 6 0's
    digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  }
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 1); // 7th bit
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 1); // 8th bit
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  
  //-------------2nd: 24bit address-------------------
  //this is 00000000 00000000 00000001
  for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clk, 1);
    digitalWrite(wpin, 0); // last 23 addr bits
    digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  }
  digitalWrite(clk, 1);
  digitalWrite(wpin, 1); // first 1 addr bit (reading from R to L)
  digitalWrite(clk, 0);

  //-------------3rd 8bit code-----------------------
  //this should be 11100111
  byte result = 0;
  String strout=""; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(clk, 1);
    // In SDI mode, the transfer is two bits per clock pulse.
    strout+=bitRead(rpin, i); // is giving me 11010000 instead of 11100111
    digitalWrite(clk, 0);
  }
  Serial.println(strout); // READ bitcode into RAM address
  digitalWrite(cspin, HIGH); // finishing read operation
}

void loop() { // we have nothing to do in the loop
}

//End of program
```

Comment: Have you read how Arduino or other bit banging SPI implementations work? Or Wikipedia page about SPI?

Comment: The guys from arduino forums introduced me to bit banging and I have a pretty good idea what it is. I am not that advanced into SPI comunication though, but I also got the idea. THe code will tell you everything.

Comment: Its this chip... you see? It has some very special way of communicating even if is SPI.  Its from Microchip and they always had to add some weird way of access, indifferent of the component they sell. But after figuring out the little details and make it work, then is a very reliable component.

Comment: Can you format the code so it is more readable? How have you debugged your code? If you run the code in your head, do you think it creates the required waveforms?

Comment: I debug it by running it in 2 ways and see the results.
The first way is programming it in reality with arduino uno, and also running the arduino console in the same time for reading the output.
The second way is "exporting compiled binary" from arduino program into the simulator and watch on the output console the results.

Comment: The component has a standard SPI interface. There is nothing weird about it. Except it can, in addition to SPI, use dual and quad data interfaces, which at this point is not important.

Comment: Indeed. All I need is NOT to comunicate through a standard SPI way, but through bitbanging, simulating a SPI comunication. If is clear enough. THats my intention. Manual comunication, the most basic way possible.

Comment: Unfortunatly this forum has no way of "attachments" to link you the actual save file from arduino. At least I can not see it.

Comment: And also there is no visible or possible way of sending to you via private chat the file, wow, what a forum, haha. But I can do this: I can link the save file externally and link it here.

Comment: Alright: here is the save file from my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JSIFmu0wUDuUgSWnb5aNEusKrIdMjDQZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding. You need to talk to the chip using SPI protocol because the chip uses it, and you can implement SPI protocol with bitbanging it in software. Attaching Arduino projects is not useful, they are not text files that can be simply opened. This is a Q&A site, not a traditional forum. It's enough if you format your post so it is readable.

Comment: Just trust me, click on the link I just post and you will get access to the file to download it.

Comment: No misunderstanding here. You said exactly what I was explained I did already. 
In the first try, I used only SPI comunication from a test code that did exactly that, using a special SPI.h library in arduino. AFTER that code that worked, I decided I want more detail and to communicate more in depth, and the solution was bit banging that some wonderful guy from arduino forums mentioned to me and we constructed the code acordingly, folowing his advice and corrections along the way.

Comment: The summary of my code is very simple: I write this: "byte bcode = 0b11100111; " that I am sending to be written into the chip at address 000...0001 (24bits long address) and then I am reading *the chip* output pin again at the same address and retrieve the data stored at that address. But instead of being 11100111 (this lovely test pattern), is something else.

Comment: Aha, you managed to correct my code editing there, very good, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that all pins are initialized as outputs. Obviously the pin from memory chip to MCU must be an input on the MCU.

But Arduino libraries already implement a working bitbanging SPI module so you can read it as an example if you want to implement it yourself.

There should be multiple SoftwareSPI modules to look from.

Comment: @All, Please stop trying to debug this in comments - the code formatting becomes lost and comments are not intended for long debugging threads anyway. The best thing I can think to do is to push these comments into chat (link below) where code won't need to be split across multiple comments etc. Please do not continue here in comments - use *only* the chat for this answer from now on, to avoid splitting the responses between comments and the chat. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139236/discussion-on-answer-by-justme-23lc1024-manual-programming).